# Groups empty when requested via Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to get list of all the teams but getting empty value even though teams are there.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups",
    "value": []
}
```

I'm hitting this endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups

Comment: What authentication model are you using? Application or Delegated?

Comment: Do you have all required permissions as mentioned in the document?